# Accessing a value by index in enumerate for-loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to access a previous value (by index) in a for loop. So I have a condition where I want to compare the value of i to i-1, but don't think I'm doing this correctly:

```
for i, f in enumerate(df[col1]):
  if f[i] < f[i-1]:
      do something
```

So in the above code I would try to compare df[col1][1] to df[col][0]. Completely hypothetical by the way. I just need to figure out the correct way to access values by index for in enumerate. Thanks

Comment: please provide a concrete example of input/output (as DataFrames)

Comment: You don't need to iterate to do this.  Use `shift` and vectorize your `do something` commands.  It will be much faster than iterating row by row of the dataframe/series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply access the column's element from its index, you can simply do and or try this:

```py
for i, f in enumerate(df['col1']):
   if df['col1'][i] < df['col1'][i - 1]:
       # do something you desire
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern in pandas.  Look at using pd.Series.shift or pd.DataFrame.shift to compare rows or even columns.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good so far. If you were to use more descriptive names it will make it easier to understand. With enumerate, you are declaring it correctly, and ordering your variables well. The only thing I see will come up is when you use [i-1] to index your list/dictionary. enumerate() begins it's count at 0, so you will end up with a negative index, and it will raise an error. You can instead use "for i, f in enumerate(df[col1], 1). The second param is the starting key it will use when enumerating over each object. Let me know how that works for you!